# Find Joint Distribution (marginal is known)

Tags: probability-distributions

Got stuck...need help on the following question

Given: $Y \sim f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\theta }e^{-\frac{y}{\theta }}$, $y>0$.

$R\sim g(r)$, $r>0$

$Y$ and $R$ are independent random variables.

$Z=YR$

Q: Find the joint density of $(Z,R)$

It is quite weird to me...

for the independency: $$f(Z)=f(Y)g(R)=\frac{1}{\theta }e^{-\frac{y}{\theta }}g(r) =\int_0^\infty f(z,r) \, dr \tag{$*$} $$

How to get

$$f(z,r)=\frac{1}{\theta }e^{-\frac{z}{r\theta }}g(r)\frac{1}{r},\qquad z>0,r>0\tag{$**$}$$

for that the fundamental theorem of Calculus cannot apply on the integration in (*), 
even if it could, it doesn't look like I could get $(**)$.

Any hint? Thanks for your time.

Comment: >for the independency: f(Z)=f(Y)g(R)  $\qquad$ This is incorrect. The density of the product $Z=YR$ is **not** the product of the densities $f(Y)$ and $g(R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use the transformation

$$Z = YR, \,\, V = R,$$

where $Y > 0$ and $R > 0$.

The inverse transformation is

$$Y = \frac{Z}{V}, \,\, R = V,$$

with Jacobian

$$J(z,v)=\frac{\partial(Y,R)}{\partial(Z,V)}=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1/v & -z/v^2 \\
0 & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right|= \frac{1}{v}.$$

The joint density of $Z$ and $V$ is

$$f_{ZV}(z,v)= f_{YR}[(Y(z,v),R(z,v)]|J(z,v)|.$$

Now use what you know about the joint density $f_{YR}$.

Comment: thanks for the hint! I'm gonna try it!!